# Asymptotically equivalent series for uniform convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, uniform-convergence

I have to find sets of uniform convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2 \sin \frac{x}{n^4}$$
what if I study this series passing to the asymptotically equivalent
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2 \frac{x}{n^4}$$
?

In this case I could use the power series theorem!

Is it correct?

Comment: You can use the limit superior of the absolute value of the inner sequence to prove many tests of convergence. If the subsequence of limit superior of absolute value converges then obviously the original sequence converges too, due to the squeeze theorem.

Comment: @Masacroso uhm I know how to solve the exercise the standard way. My question is: what's wrong in passing to the asymptotically equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

$$
f_n(x):=n^2\sin{x\over n^4}\;\forall\; n
$$

> Claim: $\;0<M<\infty\implies\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n$ converges uniformly in $[-M,M]$.

Proof: Suppose $x\in[-M,M]$. 
$$
|\sum_{n=p}^q f_n(x)|\le\sum_{n=p}^q|f_n(x)|\le\sum_{n=p}^q n^2{|x|\over n^4}\le\sum_{n=p}^q{M\over n^2}=M\sum_{n=p}^q {1\over n^2}$$
So given $\varepsilon>0$ we can find $k(\varepsilon):\forall\;p\ge q\ge k(\varepsilon)\implies$
$$
 |\sum_{n=p}^q f_n(x)|<\varepsilon\;\forall\; x\in[-M,M]
$$
as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over n^2}$ converges. So by Cauchy's criterion we're done.

> Claim: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n$ doesn't converge uniformly on $[0,\infty[$

Proof: Suppose our claim is not true. So $\exists k\in\mathbb{N}:p\ge q\ge k\implies$ 
$$
|\sum_{n=p}^q f_n(x)|<1\;\forall\; x\in[0,\infty[
$$
Fix $x={k^4\pi\over2}\in[0,\infty[$. Letting $p=q=k$ we see
$$
|\sum_{n=p}^q f_n(x)|=k^2\ge1
$$
which is a contradiction.

Similarly, $]-\infty,0]$ is not a set of uniform convergence.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But my question was a bit different: in general could i study asymptotically equivalent series in order to find sets of uniform convergence?